# Wrong collation creates invalid markers laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm developing a laravel app in my localhost which is a windows laptop but my app server is in a linux server.
When I'm developing and saving in a textarea some random text with special chars like "Ç ~ º" everything is well saved in db and showed in browser. The problem is in the server (linux), it creates specials chars like "pÃ¡tio  nÂº 64/2 " and shows bad in the browser.

I've tried to change collation in the config/database.php file to the same as the db (we use portuguese collation) 'collation' => 'Latin1_General_CI_AS' and charset =>'utf8' but nothing changed.

Any ideas? I'm using a sql server database
If I change the charset to latin1 isntead of utf8 the server shows a error

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55
SQLSTATE [] (null) (severity o)
```

I've also tried ot use html decode entities before save in the db but didn't work.
I really need some help in this issue...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I've tried the most of that answers and nothing so far..

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `collate` and `charset`. If you're are able to set `collate` and `charset` via `config/database.php` then you may do this way (for mysql):

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

But if you don't want to change DB collation then you have an option to change collation and charset for a specific table only. To do that use the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: The first two changes raises error PDOException in Connector.php line 55
SQLSTATE [] (null) (severity o)

Comment: ALTER TABLE your_table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'." My table is WFQ_Acoes

Comment: Did you replace `your_table_name` with your table name?

Comment: yes ALTER TABLE WFQ_Acoes CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: What is the mysql version?

Comment: I use sql server

Answer (score 0):

In my controller I've used this before save,

$var =  iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $request->input ( 'input1' ));